# How to send a variable as an clipboard with batch file

Tags: batch-file, clipboard

I can't send a ready variable to CLIPBOARD

I'm trying to get some data from a txt file generated with gswin64c , then delete two first spaces from this data and send it to clipboard using command CLIP.

the data inside Content.txt is :

> 016<3885180>190787>21246299690091:

With two spaces before 016

I use

```
set /p input=<Content.txt
```

to read this data and save it in a variable which name it "input"

Then I show it  using this echo command

```
echo %input%
```

Then I try to send it to CLIPBOARD without two first characters which are the two fist spaces

```
echo %input:~2% | CLIP
```

But I don't get this last command run as expected, So I don't get content of this variable on my clipboad

Comment: Nice, you don't ask a question, nor you describe any problems. Btw. It's unimportant which program creates the content. Without showing the content nobody knows what you expect to see

Comment: I tried to make some edition to make more clear, could you please help me

Comment: Without escaping `^` or enclosing in double quotes you can't echo `<>`, they are being interpreted as redirection characters (lol, you use redirection yourself with the input)

Comment: @LotPings can you show me the exact way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```bat
@Set /P "input="<"content.txt"
@Set /P "=%input:~2%"<NUL|Clip
```

Comment: Thank you Mr @Compo for your help, which I appreciate, The only data that I have on this pdf files are CMC7 code like of checks like the one you have on my question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of stripping two characters I would let [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) remove the leading spaces:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= " %%I in ("Content.txt") do (
    set "LINE=%%I" & cmd /V /C echo/!LINE!| clip
    goto :NEXT
)
:NEXT
```

The lines `goto :NEXT` and `:NEXT` are not needed when the text file `Content.txt` contains only a single line, or when you want to return the last line rather than the first one.